# How to fix " '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get' " when trying to update wrongly a form

Tags: python, django

Guys I have a simple book model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(_('ISBN'),
        validators=[RegexValidator('^[0-9 -]+$', message="ISBN must contains only numbers or hyphens!")] ,
        max_length=13, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('Book\'s title'), max_length=128)
    publisher = models.CharField(_('Publisher'), max_length=64)
    author = models.CharField(_('Author'), max_length=64)
    pages = models.IntegerField(_('Pages'), default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('books:detail', kwargs={'isbn': self.isbn})
```

Im coding a crud system and having problem with the UpdateView.
This view works properly when I try to do a correct update, but when I insert wrong values (like letters in isbn or letters in pages) I have this error:

```
Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('31234-11a',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['books/update/(?P<isbn>[\\d\\-]+)/$']
```

**EDIT**: 
This is my view:

```
class BookUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """Update the requested book."""
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(isbn=self.kwargs['isbn'])
        if not queryset.exists():
            messages.error(self.request, 'This book doesnt exist!')
            return get_object_or_404(Book, **self.kwargs)
        return queryset.get()

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'The book updated successfully!')
        return reverse_lazy('books:detail', kwargs = {'isbn': self.object.isbn})

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, 'The update has failed')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

and my update url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^update/(?P<isbn>[\d\-]+)/$', view=views.BookUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
]
```

I need to use Django 1.10 in this project idk why. If someone can reccomend me some material to read, or answer the question wold be nice. Thank you

Comment: The `form_invalid(..)` can not return a `reverse(..)` or `reverse_lazy(..)`, it can however return a `redirect(..)`.

Comment: Oh my god, I've been trying to fix this for hours, I've re-written all the methods of UpdateView, thak you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods can *not* return a `lazy_reverse(..)` object, since that is not a HTTP response.

You can however use [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), which will construct a HTTP response, like:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class BookUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """Update the requested book."""
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm

    # ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'The book updated successfully!')
        return reverse_lazy('books:detail', kwargs = {'isbn': self.object.isbn})

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, 'The update has failed')
        return redirect('books:index')
```

You can probably slightly improve your `get_object` method with:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class BookUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """Update the requested book."""
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        try:
            return queryset.get(isbn=self.kwargs['isbn'])
        except:
            messages.error(self.request, 'This book doesnt exist!')
            raise Http404('Book does not exist')
```

It is however *not* very common to `redirect(..)` in case of a `form_invalid(..)`. Usually the template is *rerendered* with the form such that the form is rendered with error messages. Therefore it is not very common to override the `form_invalid` method: by default Django will rerender the template with the invalid form.

**EDIT**: you can redirect the page to another page if the `isbn` does not map on a valid as follows:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class BookUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """Update the requested book."""
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm

    # ...

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except (ObjectDoesNotExist, Http404):
            return redirect('books:index')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

Comment: The changes that you have made in `get_success_url` and `get_object` methods return an 404 error when I run. I kept the reverse_lazy in `get_succes...` and my `get_object`. Works fine but returns `AssertionError: The form 'form' was not used to render the respons` in my view_tests.

Comment: Well no, because you're redirecting away from the page with the form on. I'm not sure why you want to do that, it means the user will never know why the form was invalid.

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: sorry somehow I had the idea that `get_success_url` was `form_success`. As for the `get_object`, I think if you have multiple `Book` objects, then there is probably something wrong

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: but as DanielRoseman says, typically you do not redirect in case of an *unsuccessful* form in the first place. You then typically render the page again, and the form will render itself with some errors.

Comment: I want the user to go to the index page when he try to submit a poorly filled form, should not I use 'redirect' then?

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: well a common pattern is to render the page again with the invalid form. It will then show what is wrong with the form by rendering some error messages. Evidently if you redirect, you do not render the form in that case.

Comment: Im coding this for an challenge, i have read the problem statments again and I am doing this wrong. I need to redirect to index page when user write an url wrong, like: `/update/anything` instead of `/update/133123`. I will edit the original post.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: see edit, you can redirect in case it raises an `ObjectDoesNotExist` or `Http404` (or some other exception).

Comment: The error `Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('31234-1a',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['books/update/(?P<isbn>[\\d\\-]+)/$']` continues when I try to update with invalid values. And when I insert a wrong url i get `name 'ObjectDoesNotExist' is not defined`

Comment: Btw you have misspelled a `this` in `get` method. Using just the http404 works fine. This part is over thank you.

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: you should import the `ObjectDoesNotExist`, furthermore this `update` is indeed not valid, since in your `urls.py`, you specified that only a sequence of digits (`[\\d-]+`) is accepted, so the view never gets control here.

Answer (score -1):

you can also just create the reverse lazy in a variable and redirect with the variable that works perfectly fine :

instead of

```
return reverse_lazy('books:detail', kwargs = {'isbn': self.object.isbn})
```

use:

```
url_match = reverse_lazy('books:detail', kwargs = {'isbn': self.object.isbn})
return redirect(url_match)
```